# Sencha Cmd 5.1 error on updating Extjs framework relative/absolute path

Tags: ruby, extjs, compass-sass, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha Cmd 5.1 to build my Extjs 5.1.0  application.

** when i  change the ext framework path under 
.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg file to **

```
ext.dir =../ext
```

**or some absolute path**  like C:\Temp\Framework\ext  then it throw the following error. looks like it is finding the ext framework but failed to import other files within that file.
 is this a ruby compile issue ? I will really appreciate your help!!

any ideas ?

```
   [exec] [INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime


  ****[exec]     error ReviewViolations-example.scss (Line 2 of ../../../../../../ext/packages/ext-theme-neutral/sass/var/grid/column/Widget.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../form/field/Base.scss.****


  [exec] Load paths:
  [exec]   D:/Build_Trunk/target/sencha/ReviewViolations/build/temp/production/ReviewViolations/slicer-temp
  [exec]   D:/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  [exec]   D:/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  [exec]   Compass::SpriteImporter)
  [exec]    create ReviewViolations-example.css 
  [exec] [ERR] 
  [exec] [ERR] BUILD FAILED
  [exec] [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
  [exec] [ERR]  at c
  [exec] [ERR] om.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:252)
```

Comment: `sencha.cfg` file is generated from sencha cmd while creating extjs app, why you're modifying it ?

Comment: @Abhijit I know this file has the default configuration but i want to keep the ext framework outside of a project so that all the projects in the company can use the same library and we don't have to check in the ext library in subversion. so i am trying a  relative or absolute path in this file

Comment: "i want to keep the ext framework outside of a project so that all the projects in the company can use the same library" - you need to generate workspace then. See http://extjs.eu/videos - the last video on the page.

Comment: @saki thanks.   even with the workspaces, i still have to add my applications inside/under  a workspace directory. i was thinking of something like unzip your framework in a folder like workspace and then your projects  are under projects & they can refer to  ext library in worlspace. It is all good in development mode but we are thinking how to efficiently build on QA /Prod build box that is commons for all the teams.

Comment: The production build contains all used Ext and application classes packed in one file app.js. The directory structure used during development is therefore irrelevant. Try to run "sencha app build" to see what it produces.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `ext.dir=${workspace.dir}/../SDK` which has worked for me in the past. Hard to say if our situations were exactly the same though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that changing the "ext.dir" config your paths to sass files exceed the maximum length of 256 chars in Windows. Take a look at the ReviewViolations-example.scss generated file.

Try to build sencha app in a Unix environment to be sure this is the problem, it should be work correctly!

I still don't have a satisfying solution.

Comment: I answered to "any ideas?". I found the problem and its "obvious" solutions, as reducing path of sass files to import.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder hierarchy is too deep and long. Reduce the level of "../../../.." and try. The path length cant exceed more than 256 chars. You can look into .sencha/app/build-impl.xml in your app. If you can change the reference to your library before build or copy the library along with your app to a temp folder before you compile production/testing version of the app.